# Is it possible to assign multiple values in a single variable (batch file)? If not, Is there a way to run this in a more efficient way?

Tags: batch-file, variables, autohotkey

I have a 2 batch file here that behaves like a timer

1st batch file

```
 @echo off

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (time.txt) do (
set TEXT=%%a
)

timeout 60
set /a "RESULT"=%TEXT%+60
echo %RESULT% > time.txt

REM UNSORTED FILES
IF %RESULT%==43200 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==86400 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==129600 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

REM FOLDERMOVER
IF %RESULT%==43200 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==86400 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==129600 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==172800 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

REM ADOBE FILES
IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\Desktop Portal\ADOBE OUTPUTS\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\Desktop Portal\ADOBE OUTPUTS\ADOBEMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

REM IMPORT
IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\IMPORT\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)


IF not %RESULT%==172860 (
D:
cd "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\PART2.ahk"
) ELSE (
goto end
)

exit

:end
set a=0
goto count
```

2nd batch file

```
@echo off

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (time.txt) do (
set TEXT=%%a
)

timeout 60
set /a "RESULT"=%TEXT%+60
echo %RESULT% > time.txt

REM UNSORTED FILES
IF %RESULT%==43200 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==86400 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==129600 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\UNSORTED\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
)

REM FOLDERMOVER
IF %RESULT%==43200 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==86400 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==129600 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

IF %RESULT%==172800 (
C:
cd "\Desktop\"
AutoHotkey.exe "\Desktop\FOLDERMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

REM ADOBE FILES
IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\Desktop Portal\ADOBE OUTPUTS\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\Desktop Portal\ADOBE OUTPUTS\ADOBEMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)

REM IMPORT
IF %RESULT%==172800 (
D:
cd "D:\IMPORT\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTMOVERCALLER.ahk"
)


IF not %RESULT%==172860 (
D:
cd "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\"
AutoHotkey.exe "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\PART1.ahk"
) ELSE (
goto end
)

exit

:end
set a=0
goto count
```

Both of them behave something like a timer. (PS the "set /a "RESULT"=%TEXT%+60" above is for adding 60sec/ 1 minute. They start each other with a ahk. script so I can start them hidden and without prompting a console.

The code inside of the.ahk script is this

```
  #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

run, "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\PART1 or PART2 .bat"

Exit
```

The batch files are working but I'm thinking if there's a more efficient way of doing these scripts and not needing too many "if's". I'm thinking about assigning multiple values in a single variable but I'm not even sure if it's possible. I'm also open in other ways.

EDIT:

Is this version of the earlier code more efficient now?

```
@echo off
:count
set /p output=<time.txt

:start
timeout /t 2
echo %output%
:cut
set /a out=%output%+2
(echo %out%)> time.txt

(call :code%output%)>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto code8

:code2
REM DESKTOP
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

:code4
REM IMPORT
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

:code6
REM UNSORTED
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

:code8
if %out% geq 8 (
    set output=0
    goto cut
  ) else (
    goto start
  )
```

I changed the following:

set /a output+=2  ==>  set /a out=%output%+2

Because It just closes when I apply the `set /a output+=2`

I also changed the `:end` label to `:code8` making the label `:code8` more easier to call.

Does this changes okay and does it run more efficient now?

**EDIT**

```
Example: Which one is correct
```

THIS ONE:

```
:code2   
start "" "D:\SCRIPT\INSTALLER\TIMER\tst - Copy.bat"   
exit /b   
start "" "D:\SCRIPT\INSTALLER\TIMER\tst - Copy2.bat"   
exit /b
```

OR THIS ONE:

```
:code2   
start "" "D:\SCRIPT\INSTALLER\TIMER\tst - Copy.bat"    
start "" "D:\SCRIPT\INSTALLER\TIMER\tst - Copy2.bat"   
exit /b
```

Comment: Why don't you use scheduled tasks for repetitive tasks? (see `schtasks /create /?` to get an idea what they are able to do; There is also a [GUI](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-open-task-scheduler-on-windows-10.html), if you prefer.

Comment: @Stephan - Thank you, I will look forward in using scheduled task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a Scheduled task will help you time everything properly, but seeing as you have written the code, I might as well try and help.

I am not going to do all the code for you, but I will show you the idea and you can complete it:

```
@echo off
set /p result=<time.txt
timeout /t 60
(set /a result+=60)>time.txt
(call :code%result%)>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto :end

:code43200
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
do the other things here for code 43200
exit /b

:code172800
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\UNSORTED\STARTCALLER4.ahk"
echo do other things here for code 172800
exit /b

:code172860
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\SCRIPT\TIMER\PART1.ahk"
echo do other things here for code 172800
exit /b

:end
echo do the end label stuff here.
```

So just a basic explanation. I read the `time.txt`  file's first line only using `set /p` and redirecting from file. I then simply redirect the output of the `set /a` command to the file instead of having to use another line to `echo` the result.

Now we do a call to the label where `:code%result%` will translate to the result in the file. There however is the issue that the result in the file does not match any of the codes meaning that the script will give an error. This however is good for this purpose, so now I simply check the `errorlevel` of the failed command and it then being `errorlevel 1` it will goto `:end`. If the label matches, it will goto it, complete the work and exit that label.

**EDIT**

Try not to change the method please:

```
@echo off
:count
set /p output=<time.txt

:start
timeout /t 2
echo %output%
set /a output+=2
:cut
(echo %output%)>time.txt

(call :code%output%)>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto end
goto :start
:code2
REM DESKTOP
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

:code4
REM IMPORT
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

:code6
REM UNSORTED
echo start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
exit /b

end:
if %output%  equ 8 (
    set output=0
    goto cut
  ) else (
    goto start
)
```

Comment: One quick question, If I will put more than one start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk" under a label/flag, for example :code4. Do I need to put the exit /b in the every end of start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk" or just one exit /b in the very end of the start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk" is enough.

See the edit above for more clariffication.

Comment: yes. the `exit /b` should be at the end of the label only.

Comment: thank you, I thought I should put it in every `start ""`