# Windows Command Processor Memory Usage continuously increasing problem. (Batch File)

Tags: loops, batch-file, memory

I have a batch file here below

```
    @echo off
:count
set /p output=<time.txt

:start
timeout /t 2
set /a out=%output%+2
:cut
echo %out% > time.txt

(call :code%out%)>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto end

:code2
REM DESKTOP
pushd "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\"
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
popd & exit /b
goto start

:code4
REM IMPORT
pushd "D:\IMPORT\"
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
popd & exit /b
goto start

:code6
REM UNSORTED
pushd "D:\UNSORTED"
start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
popd & exit /b
goto start

end:
if %out%==8 (
set out=0
goto cut
) else (
goto start
)
```

Every time I run this batch file, its memory usage was pretty low [USAGE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS0UU.jpg)
The problem occurs when I leave it running for at least 10 minutes because the Windows Command Processor Memory Usage continuously increasing. [USAGE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLAKR.jpg). I'm a little bit worried because I must run the batch file at least 6 hours. How do I suppose to fix this Windows Command Processor Memory Usage continuously increasing problem?

Comment: `push`? I am sure I told you `pushd` in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447049/is-it-possible-to-assign-multiple-values-in-a-single-variable-batch-file-if-n) anyway, I would suggest `start "" autohotkey.exe` instead. Not that I really consider 50mb utilization a problem. You'll need to run it for longer to see if it continues to grow.

Comment: oh, sorry for the typo. It should be pushd. What's the difference between these two? Even there's a typo, it still runs without an error.

Comment: Also, the previous batch files have the same problem, this is just much slower. The other one goes to 150Mb utilization in 10 minutes.

Comment: Because you are specifying the full path in the `autohotkey` commands. So you can infact remove the `pushd` and `popd` entirely. like I said change your commands to `start "" "AutoHotkey.exe" "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"` as well.

Comment: In order for people to assist you, you should explain what your code is supposed to do, _(without that information, how are people supposed to optimize it)_. Also you should provide us with at least some sort of indication of what each of your AHK scripts are doing. From my initial reading your entire script does not make sense.

Comment: @Compo - I usually use this code to arrange, convert and transfer some files. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447049/is-it-possible-to-assign-multiple-values-in-a-single-variable-batch-file-if-n) is the previous version of this code.

Comment: I don't care about some other code @EliazarInso, my comment is specifically about the code in your question, and that code appears as if it is supposed to do this, _(or similar with some 2 second delays)_: 1. `:Start`, 2. `@Start /D C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop /Wait AutoHotkey.exe DESKTOPCALLER.ahk` 3. `@Start /D D:\IMPORT /Wait AutoHotkey.exe IMPORTCALLER.ahk` 4. `@Start /D D:\UNSORTED /Wait AutoHotkey.exe UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk` 5. `@GoTo Start`. So unless you can provide an explanation for all of that seemingly pointless code, nobody really knows how best to make improvements for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(call :code%out%)>nul 2>&1` part requires an `exit /b` somewhere in your code.
But currently you just used `goto :count`

Comment: @Gerhard - Oh, now I get it. I thought I don't need to put exit /b. This will return the call right?

Comment: Also, Can I still add `goto start` below the `popd & exit /b`. Without the goto, the console just exits.

Comment: @EliazarInso go see the edited code at the bottom of the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447049/is-it-possible-to-assign-multiple-values-in-a-single-variable-batch-file-if-n) and please let's cleanup comments here.

Answer (score 1):

To better show you what jeb's answer tells you, it appears to be `Call`ing labelled sections, but never returning from those `Call`s.:

```
Call :code2
    Run "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
    Call :code4
        Run "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
        Call :code6
            Run "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
            Call :code0 {ErrorLevel 1}
                Call :code2
                    Run "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
                    Call :code4
                        Run "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
                        Call :code6
                            Run "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
                            Call :code0 {ErrorLevel 1}
                                Call :code2
                                    Run "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
                                    Call :code4
                                        Run "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
                                        Call :code6
                                            Run "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
                                            Call :code0 {ErrorLevel 1}
                                                Call :code2
                                                    Run "C:\Users\Eliaz\Desktop\DESKTOPCALLER.ahk"
                                                    Call :code4
                                                        Run "D:\IMPORT\IMPORTCALLER.ahk"
                                                        Call :code6
                                                            Run "D:\UNSORTED\UNSORTEDCALLER.ahk"
                                                            Call :code0 {ErrorLevel 1}
                                                                etc.
```